# how can I use one element of a list in fortran

Tags: fortran, fortran90

I need to do `x1/x2,x1/x3.....x5/x6`

I have 15x5 numbers, for example:
 `x1 = 3.98   x2 =4.09   x3 = 3.11    x4 =1.23   x5= 2.54     x6= 5.78`

and 14 numbers of `x1,x2,x3,x4,x5,x6` more

My question is how can I take in a `list (15,5)` the element `list(1,1)/list(1,2), list(1,1)/list(1,3)....`

```
PROGRAM coef
REAL, DIMENSION(15,5):: list 
REAL, DIMENSION(15,10):: y
INTEGER i,j             
OPEN (11, FILE='datoscoeficientes.dat')
OPEN (12, FILE='resultadoscoeficientes.sal')
READ (11, '(2/)') 
DO i=1,15
   READ  (11, '(6X,5(3X,F4.2)/)') (list(i,j),j=1,5) 
   WRITE (12, '(6X,5(3X,F4.2))') (list(i,j), j=1,5)
   call division(list,y)
   WRITE (12, '(40X,5(3X,F8.20))') sol
ENDDO
ENDPROGRAM

SUBROUTINE division(lista,y)
REAL, DIMENSION (15,5):: list
REAL, DIMENSION (15,10):: y
INTEGER m,n 
DO m=1,15
   IF(i/=j) THEN
          y(m,n)=(lista(m,n),(n=1,5))
          sol=y(m)/y(n)
   ENDIF
ENDDO
ENDSUBROUTINE
```

How can I do a subroutine so that I can reference elements of a row of a list?

Comment: `x1..x6` is six numbers, not five.

Comment: You use `y` as `y(m,n)` and then `y(m)` and `y(n)`, that is not possible, if it is two dimensional, it needs 2 indexes. Why should `y` be `(15,10)` at all?

Comment: `sol` is not declared or set in the main program. `i,j` are not set or declared in the subroutine.

Comment: And how can I do y(m)/y(n) in fortran, I don't know what can I do..

Comment: if `y` is a 2d array what is `y(m)/y(n)` supposed to mean? are you wanting to divide whole columns or rows or what?

Comment: As @agentp mentions... We know what the acronym sol means, so I would suggest using IMPLICIT NONE to see if the compiler complains about 'sol' and anything else.

I am not clearly following what you are trying to do. What is list_A physically representing? and what is the physical meaning of Y ?

Comment: You wrote that you want to divide `x1/x2,x1/x3.....x5/x6` which is not clear. Did you mean `x1/x2,x1/x3.....x1/x6` or `x1/x2,x2/x3.....x5/x6`? In other words, do you want to divide the first column or each column with the previous one?